# Database server setup to handle 10K inserts and to frequent select operations

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design

Currently I have a system(server) which receives message from 1000 devices(clients) at a time and each of them send message once per minute.

Each message will have more than 2000 records.

So per minute the system will receive 1000 X 2000  => 2,000,000 records

At the same time I am expecting frequent select request ( around 1000 )

Query is

What is the best way to setup database server (Mysql/postgres) to handle this frequent bulk insertion and read operation?

Comment: I just noticed you wrote 'currently I have a system'.  Can you give us more information about what you're doing? What do your records look like? What do you need to store in the DBMS? With a system of the size you describe, these details matter a great deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I just batched up 1M fake rows (one character and an int from 1 to 1000000) and inserted it in one transaction in postgresql on my laptop.  Took 4 seconds.  1Million inserts a minute is easy, at least at first.  However there's lots more to worry about.  Updating indexes, for instance, can be expensive.  I added a unique index on the integer field and the insert time went from 4s to 9s.  Inserting another 1M rows took 14 seconds.  This number will continue to climb as the index grows.  Once the index no longer fits in memory it will skyrocket.

Often the best way to handle this much data is to stuff it into discrete text files and bulk upload it at a later time with no indexes.  Then add indexes.

All the stuff Ollie mentions in his answer about MySQL will apply for most any other db as well.

PostgreSQL specific stuff:

Use connection pooling and persistent connections, keeping total connections low, say below 100.

Use FAST storage media.  The problem you have here is that you will likely need a LOT of storage, so SSDs might not work. If you have to use spinning drives, then put a LOT of them in under a RAID controller with battery backed hardware caching in RAID-10 for best performance and good reliability.  RAID-5 or 6 would be a disaster here as their write performance is terrible.

Batch as many of the writes together as you can.  Unlike some dbs that will puke on large transactions, PostgreSQL is quite comfortable with 1M or more rows at a time in a transaction.

Use as few indexes as needed.

Comment: Also look at partitioning your data into child tables.

Answer (score 3):

How are your one thousand devices connecting? If each one establishes a TCP/IP connection to your server you'll need to make sure you have enough file descriptors in the machine to which they connect.  Look at `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` to see the maximum.  A thousand client connections to a single server machine is considered a large number.

How much data is in each record? Will you overwhelm your network hardware?  If each record is ten bytes, then you're talking about twenty million bytes coming in per second, or one hundred and sixty million bits.  A 100 megabit per second ethernet interface won't be nearly enough. Even a gigabit interface is questionable: it's hard to maintain enormous throughput. Keep in mind that if the DBMS is on a different machine from the server that receives your data, these records will have to both come in and go out, doubling your network throughput.

How are you going to handle the possibility that your DBMS or some other part of your system will get behind in its workload? An occasional thirty-second delay by the DBMS in accepting INSERT commands is very possible, but an enormous amount of unhandled data will accumulate during that time.

You should consider partitioning this problem into groups of, maybe, 50 or 100 devices, and 20 or ten central server setups collecting data.  If you do that you won't have a single point of failure, you won't be pushing your networking hardware extremely hard, and you may be able to work out some kind of failover strategy if you lose some hardware. You'll also be able to use much cheaper and more cost-effective server and networking equipment.

On MySQL, use as few indexes as you can to support the queries you need to do. Keep in mind that doing summary queries (like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raw WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR`) can dramatically slow down INSERT operations while they are running.

You may want to consider using a queuing system such as ActiveMQ to handle your data flow.

Comment: also total amount of storage - how many days worth of this information makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. 
How about using infobright?

Comment: Could you expand a bit on the ActiveMQ option? Thanks

Comment: ActiveMQ (http://activemq.apache.org/) is an infrastructure for passing messages between machines. Devices can enqueue messages containing their information, and servers can dequeue those messages. Among other things it allows easier scaling up.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally optimise for *either* write *or* read, but not for both. So in this case, carefully trimming the table in size, only declare required indexes, and putting it on a fast machine, is probably your only option. Do you need to keep data for a long time, or can you flush out older data? Otherwise your table would get very large.

Comment: is Mysql master/ slave fit for this scenario?

Comment: The slave gets as much load as the master, so that doesn't really change anything. Of course, with multiple slaves, you can offload reads between them. I would say that is most likely a premature optimisation though. Focus on pruning your tables, so they don't become huge - if you can do that, you'll probably be fine (Even with thousands of queries a second).